# How To Show A Progress Bar/message till the page components get fully Loaded And Shown In The Screen

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, progress-bar

I am working on a WPF application .I have a custom progress bar built by me . Its a simple wpf app . In my application i need to show the custom progress bar till page components gets loaded . How do i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

you can do like this....

```
  //Create a Delegate that matches 
//the Signature of the ProgressBar's SetValue method

private delegate void UpdateProgressBarDelegate(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, Object value);

private void Process()
{
    //Configure the ProgressBar
    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0;
    ProgressBar1.Maximum = short.MaxValue;
    ProgressBar1.Value = 0;

    //Stores the value of the ProgressBar
    double value = 0;

    //Create a new instance of our ProgressBar Delegate that points
    // to the ProgressBar's SetValue method.
    UpdateProgressBarDelegate updatePbDelegate = 
        new UpdateProgressBarDelegate(ProgressBar1.SetValue);

    //Tight Loop: Loop until the ProgressBar.Value reaches the max
    do
    {
        value += 1;

        /*Update the Value of the ProgressBar:
            1) Pass the "updatePbDelegate" delegate
               that points to the ProgressBar1.SetValue method
            2) Set the DispatcherPriority to "Background"
            3) Pass an Object() Array containing the property
               to update (ProgressBar.ValueProperty) and the new value */
        Dispatcher.Invoke(updatePbDelegate, 
            System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background, 
            new object[] { ProgressBar.ValueProperty, value });
    }
    while (ProgressBar1.Value != ProgressBar1.Maximum);
}
```

pls go through this link [for more info](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-progressbar/)

pls go through this link for [another progress bar types](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-progressbar/) ...

Answer (score 1):

You may also use a "BackgroundWorker" to implement this.

Example:-
http://midnightprogrammer.net/post/Using-Background-Worker-in-C.aspx